# Who wrote the "Mi General Augusto Pinochet" Song?

Tags: 20th-century, music, dictatorship, chile

It is available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9R4zPTpS9w). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augusto_Pinochet), *mi general* was a nickname sometimes used by General Pinochet's supporters.

Is it modern or contemporary? In the former case I would like to know who wrote it.

Comment: Oldest reference I could find online with a quickie search was April of 2015 (and uncredited). I'd find that suspicious for a song in English, but for a South American Spanish song, I don't know. Also, the guy seems to have become a modern Nazi hero. I need a brain bath.

Comment: That YouTube link is presently broken; is there another reference for the song?

Answer (score 5):

There are earlier references to this song, however, the most complete version of this song I was able to find was this one.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XD5nL0Toh7w

It not only includes much clearer audio than any other version; it also has a speech at the beginning over an instrumental of the song, confirming that the instrumentals and vocals were recorded separately.

The song clearly mentions its author as *Luis Checho Gonzalez Jimenez.* After some digging, I found a Wikipedia page about a Chilean 70's singer called Luis "Checho" Orlando Gonzalez Jimenez.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usuario:DiarioElTarapaca/Taller

Comment: Nice work. Here is another source that credits him with the song: https://pesniclub.com/text/luis-checho-gonsales-general-augusto-pinochet

Comment: In case it's not obvious, the Wikipedia link is to someone's private notes, not to an official Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Willy Bascuñan is the composer as well as singer.

https://www.watzatsong.com/en/found/Willy+Bascunan-Adios+Mi+General+Adios-429897.html

The song is Adios Mi General and it was composed after Pinochet's death. Somehow it seems that it is being used by a far right podcast.

Comment: Sources would greatly improve this answer.